# How can I perform this sql update using sql instead of using code?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have been able to select this data, using these two sql queries

[image]

Query 1:

```
SELECT article_id, amount_required, amount_sold FROM products_articles,sales WHERE sales.product_id = products_articles.product_id
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
```

What I want to do, is go through the first table (with amount sold and required) (it's fine that there are duplicate rows), and for each row in the table multiply the value of amount_sold and amount_required and then subtract that value from amount_in_stock where the ids match in the second table.

Example from the first row:
2 * 4 = 8, change amount_in_stock from 124 to 116.
And so on...

How can I do this using just sql?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Where to store the new values?

Comment: I've done this using javascript - foreach of the items in the list, multiply those two values and then loop through the articles table - if the ids match then I subtract the value from the original. So it's not about storing new values it's about updating the amount_in_stock value in the articles table

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE A
SET 
    A.amount_in_stock =(S.amountSold * S.amount_required)- A.amount_in_stock 
FROM articles AS A
INNER JOIN
products_articles AS PA
ON PA.article_id= A.article_id
INNER JOIN  Sales AS S 
ON S.product_id=PA.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
Update articles a
inner join 
(
SELECT article_id, sum(amount_required) amount_required, sum(amount_sold )amount_sold FROM products_articles inner join sales on sales.product_id = products_articles.product_id
group by article_id
)b on a.article_id=b.article_id
set a.amount_in_stock=a.amount_in_stock-(amount_required*amount_sold )
```

Since there could be multiple rows in product_articles and amount_sold I have used group by to sum the amounts.

For SQLite please try this:

```
Update articles 
set amount_in_stock=(SELECT  sum(amount_required) * sum(amount_sold )  FROM products_articles inner join sales on sales.product_id = products_articles.product_id
where products_articles.article_id=articles.article_id
group by article_id
)
where exists (SELECT  *  FROM products_articles inner join sales on sales.product_id = products_articles.product_id where products_articles.article_id=articles.article_id
)
```

Comment: @Yonder Are you facing any difficulties with this query anymore?

Comment: This worked perfectly (for mariadb), thank you, and it was a good solution, and easy to understand. Then I had to make it work for sqlite, and I got stuck on that update and inner join doesn't work there

Comment: Are you still stuck with sqlite? Please let me know? And please add SQLite tag in  the question.